# Can't css font-family for option select box

Tags: css

I can't css font-family:'Kittithada Medium 65' for option , and i wonder that is option or not ??
[this is select box that is needed css font-family](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8sNa.jpg)

This is link to check https://levis-dev.acommercedev.com/th/men.html

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to apply the font?

Comment: [it's already applied](https://image.ibb.co/jHbwSv/Capture.png)

Comment: yeah, i found my problem, that font is not apply for option select box but other element  is applied , i try other font and all is appied . thank you so much